# Получение значения элемента HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Как получить значение одного элемента `HashMap`? Мне нужно сделать метод, где будет сравниваться значение `HashMap` и если такого нету в нем, то добавлять.
Код должен сначала поделить емейлы, а потом посчитать домены.

```
public void statistics() {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, String> sortedMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfEmails.size(); i++) {
        String value = listOfEmails.set(i, listOfEmails.get(i).split("@")[1]);
        map.put(i, listOfEmails.set(i, value));
        //System.out.println(map.get(i).toString());
        for (int k = 0; k < map.size(); k++) {
            String domen = map.get(k);
            int count = 1;

            // проходится по массиву с значением
            for (int l = 0; l < map.size(); l++) {
                if (sortedMap.get(domen) == null) {
                    sortedMap.put(k, domen);
                } else {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sortedMap.get(k) + " col=" + count);
        }
```

Comment: `Как получить значение одного элемента HashMap` - есть метод `get` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-). можно начать с него

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в `get` я передаю ключ, а мне нужно передать значение

Comment: `public boolean containsValue(Object value)
Returns true if this map maps one or more keys to the specified value.` Чуть ниже по той же ссылке

Comment: итератором по всей мапе бежать и сравнивать, а для чего тогда нужен ключ? Возможно можно поменять ключ и значение местами или вообще отказаться от мапы

Comment: @Pro100Denysko из твоего вопроса следует совсем наоборот, нежели ты написал в комментарии......тогда `containsValue`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,  обновил вопрос